# Redirect a call mid-call with Twilio

Tags: twilio

I am using Twilio Client in my application, and I was wondering if there's a way to redirect a call mid-call on key press.

To be more accurate, is there a way to set up a listener for a specific key and Gather on keypress? I saw that Twilio recommends using hang up on star for these kind of things, but this option only listens to the caller's key presses, and I want to have the ability to redirect even if the call is inbound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a nice solution.

Instead of making a call using a one dial from a client/number to a client/number, what I did is create a conference call even if there are only 2 people speaking. This way both of the sides use the Dial verb and I can use hangUpOnStar on both the caller and the recipient.